# Visual Studio подчеркивает код, показывает ошибки

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Работаю над двумя проектами на `c#` и переключаюсь между ними. Исользую `Visual Studio 2022`.

Сегдоня открыл проект в который надо внести только небольшие правки и IDE показывает мне 1762 ошибки и подчеркивает код.

Это вывод `Error list` (начало):

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Reflection' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   kodeClvsc   C:\Users\Dmitry\p\kodeClvsc\CreatePdf.cs    5   Active
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Collections' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  kodeClvsc   C:\Users\Dmitry\p\kodeClvsc\CreatePdf.cs    6   Active
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) kodeClvsc   C:\Users\Dmitry\p\kodeClvsc\CreatePdf.cs    8   Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  kodeClvsc   C:\Users\Dmitry\p\kodeClvsc\CreatePdf.cs    12  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported  kodeClvsc   C:\Users\Dmitry\p\kodeClvsc\CreatePdf.cs    14  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported  kodeClvsc   C:\Users\Dmitry\p\kodeClvsc\CreatePdf.cs    15  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  kodeClvsc   C:\Users\Dmitry\p\kodeClvsc\CreatePdf.cs    16  Active
```

Но если собрать проект и запустить через Visual Studio, то все прекрасно собирается и работает. Но ошибки и подчеркивание не пропадают в самой среде.

Понятно, что и ошибки на пустом месте, потому что `namespace` подгружены через `using`-директиву. Но и там тоже подчеркивается импорт

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто сталкивался с подобным поведением `Visual Studio`, подскажите,  как поправить

Comment: Удалите `obj` и `bin` директории из проекта, перезапустите студию, нажмите "Пересобрать" проект.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ безрезультатно

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Но, склонировал проект по новой в новое место и все пропало. Странный VS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В принципе не понятно, что происходит, но похоже на баг самой IDE.

Сделал две вещи

1. Удалил папки `obj` и `bin` в директории проекта, перезапустил студию, пересобрал (мне не помогло)
2. Создал новую папку и склонировал проект в это новое место (помогло)

Универсального ответа так и нет, поскольку может сложиться ситуация, что удаленного репозитория нет, а первый указанный вариант не срабатывает.